# how do I enable double click in action script?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I tried to do this :

```
panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,showEditPopup);
```

but it is not working.

It works fine for

```
panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showEditPopup);
```

So, I guess I have to enable double click first. Need help on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to enable double click for your panel before by doing this :

```
panel.doubleClickEnabled=true;
```

And then you can do :

```
panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,showEditPopup);
```

Comment: Do note, MouseEvent.CLICK will also Fire Twice.

Comment: I wonder what is the rationale behind this API design? Why don't we need to set `panel.clickEnabled = true` for a single click and need for double click?

Comment: In some situations, you may also need to set `mouseChildren` to `false` for `doubleClickEnabled` to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem this morning trying to add a double click to my game.
This is what i found out.

First of all you gotta enable doubleclick like this:

```
panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,showEditPopup);
```

You can also add the singe CLICK on the same function to prevent click to happen twice when double clicking, like this:

```
panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,showEditPopup);
```

Then this would be the function, interacting with both but 1 at a time:

```
function showEditPopup(e:MouseEvent) {
  if (e.type == "click") {
    //single click
  } else if (e.type == "doubleClick") {
    //double click
  }
}
```

Now there is 2 problem that come up. First you gotta enable double click like this before the listener:

```
panel.enableDoubleClick = true;
```

Then the worse, if the display object is binded to another display object, which have a mouse event, you have to disable those event for the children so the double click work. Like this:

```
panel.mouseChildren = false;
```

That was bad for me because this is what i was doing.
Created a card with skills, skills had mouseevent.move_over to show a tooltip. But then i wanted to double click the card to place it/remove it from the deck. But it was not working because the skills, attached to that movieclip, had mouseevent in them. So i had to disable them and find another way to do it. Because tooltip wasnt showing with that mousechildren set to false and i had no choice to have this to bypass those event.

And this is why the timer solution seem a better idea indeed.You can go as up as 1 second for the wait time of a double click. It won't affect people and will fit even the slowest dude ;)